# Adding invalid class CSS for radiobutton

Tags: css, sass

I am creating my own *css* for a radiobutton, but I have a problem with invalid state. Below is my *scss* for the whole radiobutton with all states like `checked` and `disabled`. I would like to add it to its class, that will describe how the radiobutton should look like when its declared as invalid.

My code:

```
@mixin radioStyle($borderSize,
    $borderColor, 
    $dotColor,
    $focusColor,
    $insideRadioColor,
    $borderRadius,
    $transition,
    $width:1.125rem,
    $height:1.125rem,) {
      .radiobutton {
        input[type="radio"] {
          + .radiobutton__label  {
            &:before {
              height: $height;
              width: $width;
              border-radius: $borderRadius;
              border:  $borderSize solid $borderColor;
              transition: $transition;
            }
          }
            &:checked {
                + .radiobutton__label  {
                  &:before {
                    background-color: $dotColor;
                    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px $insideRadioColor;
                  }
                }
              } 
              
            &:disabled {
                + .radiobutton__label  {
                  &:before {
                    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px $insideRadioColor;
                  }
                }
              }
            &:focus {
                + .radiobutton__label  {
                  &:before {
                    outline: none;
                    border-color: $focusColor;
                        }
                      }
                    }
                      
                  }
                }
              }
.radiobutton {
  input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    + .radiobutton__label  {
      &:before {
        content: '';
        margin-right: 0.5em; 
        vertical-align: top;
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-flex;
      }
    }
    &:focus {
      + .radiobutton__label  {
        &:before {
          outline: none;
        }
      }
    }
    + .radiobutton__label  {
      &:empty {
        &:before {
        }
      }
    }
    +.radiobutton__label +.invalid {
        &:before {
          border-color: red;
        }
      
    }
  }
 
  input:disabled+label {
      opacity: .3;
    }
}
@include radioStyle(2px, $cytiva-color-shade-gray-1,
 $cytiva-color-primary-green,
  $cytiva-color-secondary-lightblue,
  $cytiva-color-primary-white,
  100%,all 250ms ease);
```

I would like to add the class `.invalid` that makes `border-color: red`.
Does anybody know how to add it?

My html:

```
<div class="radiobutton">
  <input id="radio-1" name="radiobutton" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="radio-1" class="radiobutton__label ">Checked</label>
</div>
<div class="radiobutton">
  <input id="radio-2" name="radiobutton" type="radio">
  <label  for="radio-2" class="radiobutton__label ">Unchecked</label>
</div>
<div class="radiobutton">
  <input id="radio-3" name="radiobutton" type="radio" disabled>
  <label for="radio-3" class="radiobutton__label ">Disabled</label>
</div>
<div class="radiobutton">
  <input id="radio-2" name="radiobutton" type="radio" >
  <label  for="radio-2" class="radiobutton__label invalid">Invalid</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you do it directly with `&:invalid { border-color: red } `?

Comment: it does not work

Comment: Post also your html. It is hard to reproduce without it.

Comment: ok, html is added

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via this selector:

```
input:invalid ~ .radiobutton__label:before {
  background: red;
}
```

It selects the before element of the next sibling of an invalid input. You can check it out it in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/QWyaxRK?editors=1111). I gave the button the attribute `required` and a `value="null"` to simulate the invalid status.

**UPDATE**:
My example was with the background color. In order update the border-color, you have to get more specific. The selector should look like this:

```
input[type="radio"]:invalid ~ .radiobutton__label:before {
  border-color: red;
}
```

I also updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/QWyaxRK?editors=1111).

Comment: I see, but still it is not possible for border-color